# view doesn't display specific type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, tempdata

I am using asp.net to create a website . I am able to get the data and store in TempData, but when i display it in the view it shows blank for id and subject.

I have checked in debugging that the data is proper in the database and it is getting stored in the tempdata also. The problem is subject and id are not being shown in the view.

does the id being PK and int and email_subject being null causing the problem as I am able to display the other columns.

If yes can you please tell me why?

Code in my view is ..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>




    @{


        Html.BeginForm();


        @Html.Label("Email_Subject", "Email_Subject :   ")
        <h3> @TempData["email_subject"]</h3>
        <br />
        
        @Html.Label("Body", "Body :   ")
        <h3> @TempData["body"] </h3>
        <br />

        @Html.Label("Predicted", "Predicted :  ")
        <h3> @TempData["intent"]</h3>
        <br />

        <input type="Submit" name="Correctornot" value="Correct" />
        <input type="Submit" name="Correctornot" value="Not Correct" />
        <br />

        Html.EndForm();


    }
```

Code in my controller is...

```html
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()

        {

            string connstr = connection string ;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" Select top(1) Id , Body , Email_subject , Queue , Intent , Tagging FROM [dbo].[Labeler_Email_for_Confirmation]      ");

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;



            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())

            {
                
                var Did = reader["Id"].ToString();
                TempData["id "] = Int64.Parse(Did);

                TempData["email_subject "] = reader["Email_subject"].ToString();
                TempData["body"] = reader["Body"].ToString();
                TempData["intent"] = reader["Intent"].ToString();

                TempData["queue"] = reader["Queue"].ToString();
                TempData["tagging"] = reader["Tagging"].ToString();


            }


            conn.Close();




            TempData.Keep();

            return View();

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. There is no way to know why something does not render without seeing what you actually *do render* and what data actually is. Make sure to inline all necessary data in your code sample while [edit] the question.

Comment: I have edited the question with snippets of required code used in rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It was a complete different problem. Actually while defining the TempData i have by mistake added a space after id and email_subject name. And while trying to display I didn't have the space. So basically I was trying to get a Tempdata totally different than the one i created so it showed the blank.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    @{

     var Email_Subject = "";  
         var body = "";  
     var intent = "";
    if (TempData.ContainsKey("Email_Subject"))  
        {  
        Email_Subject = TempData["Email_Subject"] as string;  
        }
    if (TempData.ContainsKey("body"))  
        {  
        body = TempData["body"] as string;  
        }    
    if (TempData.ContainsKey("intent"))  
        {  
        intent = TempData["intent"] as string;  
        }    
        Html.BeginForm();


       
        <h3> @Email_Subject</h3>
        <br />
        
     
        <h3> @body </h3>
        <br />

       
        <h3> @intent</h3>
        <br />

        <input type="Submit" name="Correctornot" value="Correct" />
        <input type="Submit" name="Correctornot" value="Not Correct" />
        <br />

        Html.EndForm();


    }
```